# SWTException: Widget is disposed

Tags: java, swt

When I create open new SWT app window a second time, app crashes with `SWTException: Widget is disposed` error. What's wrong?

Here is my code:

ABSTRACT `Controller.java`:

```
public abstract class Controller {
    protected View view;

    public Controller(View v) {
        view = v;
    }

    protected void render() {
        data();
        view.setData(data);
        view.render();
        listeners();
        if (display)
            view.open();
    }
    protected void data() {}

    protected void listeners() {}
}
```

`AboutController.java` (represends new window):

```
public class AboutController extends Controller {
    static AboutView view = new AboutView();

    public AboutController() {
        super(view);
        super.render();
    }
}
```

ABSTRACT `View.java`:

```
public abstract class View {
    protected Display display;
    protected Shell shell;
    protected int shellStyle = SWT.CLOSE | SWT.TITLE | SWT.MIN;

    private void init() {
        display = Display.getDefault();
        shell = new Shell(shellStyle);
    };

    protected abstract void createContents();

    public View() {
        init();
    }

    public void render() {
        createContents();
    }

    public void open() {
        shell.open();
        shell.layout();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my view `AboutView.java`

```
public class AboutView extends View implements ApplicationConstants {

    protected void createContents() {
        shell.setSize(343, 131);
        shell.setText("About");

        Label authorImage = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
        authorImage.setBounds(10, 10, 84, 84);
        authorImage.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(AboutView.class,
                "/resources/author.jpg"));
    }
}
```

When I try to create new app window, with `new AboutController()` then `Widget is disposed` error occurs.

Comment: Why didn't you post the exception stacktrace?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot access an already disposed widget. In your code, `AboutController.view` is static, so it is created only once when the class `AboutController` is initialized. When the `Shell` is closed, it is automatically disposed and so all child-widgets get disposed too - including your view object.

When you then open the window a second time, the already disposed view is handed over to the super-constructor instead of a newly created view.

Comment: Thank you, i got it. But how to init view and send it into super? super(new AboutView()) is good, but view stays undefined...

Comment: @user3017651 then remove the static field. Apart from that you should not do everything in the constructor! Just initialize your objects there, but do not do any render, open and so on!